# how could create my own GUI to control my own robot

Tags: ros, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! i have problem about GUI ,how could i create my own GUI to control my own robot?

i can create some Arrow key to send some data like cmd_vel and some joint_state GUI to control the joints

GUI like in this question http://answers.ros.org/question/10834/pr2-motor-control-guiinterface/

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227795/how-could-create-my-own-gui-to-control-my-own-robot/) by [peterlin300](https://answers.ros.org/users/25026/peterlin300/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe, you can try to use an rqt plugin, while rqt is intended for GUI development for ROS  http://wiki.ros.org/rqt

---

Originally posted by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) with karma: 123 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0